# CORBA and MOM integration

Tags: zeromq, corba, mom

1. Can I integrate Message Oriented Middleware like - ZeroMQ along with CORBA.
   Is it possible with TAO ?
2. Is CORBA Mssaging Service same as the Message Queue sevice provided by MOM like - 
   ZMQ /RabbitMQ.. ?

Where can I get information related to this?

Answer (score -1):

1. No
2. No

You should read a beginners guide of CORBA and ZeroMQ. Use the search engine of your choice.